# Почему один запрос к MySQL отражается на выполнении следующего

Tags: mysql

`` UPDATE `table` SET `link`=0 where `link`=X AND `type` IN (LIST);
DELETE FROM `table` where `link`=X; ``

В целевой таблице table удаляются (update) ссылки у строк определенного типа.
Затем происходит удаление оставшихся. При этом второй запрос происходит очень долго, драйвер падает с ошибкой таймаута.
Если первый запрос не выполнять, то второй, на удаление, пройдет быстро.
Индекс на поле link имеется.
Во время работы второго запроса processlist показывает state = updating

`` | Query   |   27 | updating | DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `table`.`link` = ? ``

Как с этим бороться?
v5.6.16
p.s. Обе операции происходят внутри транзакции, если операцию на обновление вынести до старта транзакции, то проблем не наблюдается.

Comment: А переменная X одинакова в первом и во втором запросе? Или они разные?

Comment: Переменная X одинаковая

Comment: Таблица маленькая = 2тыс записей, innoDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если запускать транзакцию и пытаться обновить часть строк по некоторому ключу, затем удалить (думаю это же относится и к обновлению) другие строки используя этот же ключ (индекс), то строки затронутые первым запросом будут заблокированы и следующий будет ждать снятия блокировки. Посмотреть в этот момент на сам зависший запрос можно так

`show full processlist;`

Посмотреть на текущие блокировки можно так

`select * from information_schema.innodb_locks;`

Информацию о транзакциях так

`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`

Снижение уровня изоляции транзакции при этом не решает задачу. Пока я вижу единственный работающий выход: выяснить какие из строк нужно обновить, какие удалить и выполнить два запроса используя при этом их первичные ключи, а не общие как было раньше.

Answer (score 5):

В InnoDB осуществляется блокировка на уровне строк, поэтому на время поиска или сканирования индекса таблицы устанавливается совместно используемая или эксклюзивная блокировка записей обрабатываемых индексов

Существуют следующие блокировки в InnoDB:

1. **record lock** — блокировка записи индекса
2. **gap lock** — блокировка промежутка между, до или после индексной записи
3. **next-key lock** — блокировка записи индекса и промежутка перед ней

И здесь все просто, вы одновременно выполняете запрос на удаление и на обновление, но первый запрос уже взял эксклюзивную блокировку на индекс, чтобы его никто не изменял и не читал, пока он не внесет изменения в записи.

Представьте индекс, как оглавление в книге, и вот сейчас его кто-то меняет, а еще меняет какие-то данные в книге, а Вы хотите его забрать себе (прочитать или изменить), но вы это не сможете сделать пока текущий обладатель этой книги не завершит работу. И правильно, что вы не сможете этого сделать, ведь если в один момент обладатель поменял данные, но не успел поменять оглавление, а вы его взяли читать, то оглавление будет неправильное.

У вас происходит record lock и следовательно блокируются все сущности связанные с X. Например, SELECT c1 FOR UPDATE FROM T WHERE c1 = 10; предотвращает любую другую транзакцию от вставки, обновления или удаления строк, где значение t.c1 равно 10.

Блокировки всегда используют индексные записи, даже если таблица определена без индексов. Для таких случаев InnoDB создает скрытый кластерный индекс и использует этот индекс для блокировки записей.

InnoDB использует блокировки так, чтобы полностью покрыть условие поиска блокирующего запроса и при этом заблокировать наименьшее возможное количество индексного пространства.

Comment: Вы уверены что происходит record lock? Я посмотрев https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-record-locks подумал что такого рода блокировки должны быть явными, там еще приводится пример с select for update.
Хочу обратить внимание, что обе операции (и еще несколько других) происходят внутри транзакции, я забыл это упомянуть. Так вот, если операцию update вынести перед транзакцией, проблемы нет.
И еще: в консоли тоже не получается воспроизвести проблему, все отрабатывает быстро. А вот во время автотестов зависает.

Comment: InnoDB создает транзакцию, даже когда вы ее не открываете :) Вы внутри одной транзакции последовательно (один за одним) выполняете 2 запроса? Тоесть первый запрос, он завершился и вы выполняете следующий? Или вы выполняете их параллельно? Одновременно с первым выполняется второй запрос?

Comment: нет, не параллельно, последовательно. Об этом написано в условии, ключевое слово "затем"

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю почему вы пишете что InnoDB создает транзакцию всякий раз? Блокирует строки на чтение или запись, да, но транзакция - это неделимая операция и применима может быть только к нескольким изменениям, сама по себе одиночная операция как может быть транзакцией? Я уж не говорю об операциях чтения ("InnoDB создает транзакцию, даже когда вы ее не открываете (С)") это вообще странное утверждение.
Думаю вы путаете транзакцию и блокировку.

Comment: Возможно это будет для Вас новым, но есть такое понятие как неявная транзакция, которая стартует при модификации данных одним запросом, если Вы ее не открывали вручную. По вашему запросу не особо ясно, почему тогда происходит блокировка, если Вы выполняете запросы последовательно и в рамках одной транзакции, такого по сути не должно быть. Добейтесь еще раз подобной блокировки и сделайте вывод SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS, посмотрите, нет ли в LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK ваших запросов?

Comment: Я думаю под термином "неявная транзакция" вы подразумевали автокоммит для innoDB. В процессе понимания я решил что строки после update блокируются по ключу link и последующий delete не может быть произведен. Попытка снижать уровень изоляции не помог.

Comment: Я провел данную ситуацию на MySQL, но не смог добиться блокировки при последовательных запросах в рамках транзакции. У вас это абсолютно всегда происходит? Может все-таки есть конкурирующие запросы, которые в этот момент блокируют или изменяют строки связанные с интервалами или данным ключом? Все-таки посмотрите на вывод LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK, о котором я написал выше.

Comment: Пытаясь сделать это в консоли у меня тоже не выходило. Чтобы обозначить эту проблему я написал отдельный тест и вот в нем как раз проблема проявлялась, собственно и началось все с автотестов. На всякий случай напишу чем пользовался: язык erlang, драйвер бд emysql. В любом случае спасибо за помощь и попытку разобраться!

Comment: @МаксимШломин раз в консоле это у Вас не выходило, значит проблема всетаки в тесте. Может одновременно запускаются тесты которые затрагивают одинаковые строки и впадают в DEADLOCK.

Answer (score 3):

Могу предположить что при выполнении UPDATE поля по которому есть ключ идет перестройка индекса. Если записей в таблице много - это может занять достаточно много времени.
Рекомендую попробовать сперва удалять DELETE а потом уже делать UPDATE:

DELETE FROM `table` where `link`=X AND `type` NOT IN (LIST);
UPDATE `table` SET `link`=0 where `link`=X;

Comment: Нет, записей мало, и обновление индекса происходит во время выполнения запроса, а не после. delete перед update по тому условию что у меня в задаче также заблокировал бы строки для update